# PHP Warning: ltrim() Problem in WordPress (formatting.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, error-handling

**I am writing this in shell;**

sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log

**And, I saw this;**

......

[Sun Feb 14 09:42:06.873076 2021] [php7:warn] [pid 1968] [client 82.222.237.83:36955] PHP Warning:  ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4314

[Sun Feb 14 09:42:06.873149 2021] [php7:warn] [pid 1968] [client 82.222.237.83:36955] PHP Warning:  ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4314

...

**I'm going to the relevant code.** --> /var/www/html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4314

```
function esc_url( $url, $protocols = null, $_context = 'display' ) {
    $original_url = $url;

    if ( '' === $url ) {
        return $url;
    }

    $url = str_replace( ' ', '%20', ltrim( $url ) );
    $url = preg_replace( '|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\[\]\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url );

    if ( '' === $url ) {
        return $url;
    }

    if ( 0 !== stripos( $url, 'mailto:' ) ) {
        $strip = array( '%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A' );
        $url   = _deep_replace( $strip, $url );
    }

    $url = str_replace( ';//', '://', $url );
```

**on line 4314;**

```
$url = str_replace( ' ', '%20', ltrim( $url ) );
```

I did not understand. My error page is full of this. I could not figure out despite my research. Can you help me?

*Note: Ubuntu 20.04, Wordpress*

Healthy days,
Best regards.

Comment: The function is called with an object, but not with a string... however, it's not seen here how its called....

Comment: [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-ltrim-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string/) might help

Comment: But, I am not using Pods wordpress plugin related to [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-ltrim-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string/) content. Also, unfortunately I could not read the solution completely. It is written very complex. @berend

Answer (score 1):

The function esc_url() is called with a $url that is object rather a string.  You can use gettype() or print_r() to confirm.  debug_backtrace() might be useful to figure out where you are making those calls from.